# Improving Pie Chart Graphic in Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

I have a pie chart and the smaller slices don't look so great. The texts are congested and not really readable compared to the larger slices. Is there a way I can improve this graphic? I'm wondering if its possible to write code where I have a line pointing from a small slice to the corresponding text. Here's what my chart looks like right now:

This is my code:

```
 #Pie chart of different collision types
#acc_colls
labels = 'VEH', 'FIXED OBJ', 'OTHER-COLLISION','ANIMAL','NON-COLLISION','PED','BICYCLE'
colors = 'orange', 'green', 'red','pink','yellow','blue','purple'
x=acc_colls
explode = (0, 0.2, 0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2)  # explode slice 2-4 
plt.pie(x, labels=labels, explode=explode, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=190)
plt.title('Collision Types')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include `plt.legend` so that your pie names are at a different place. YOu can also use `radius` to increase the size of the pie chart. On top of that, you can use the size of the `figure` too.

You can either use `subplot` or the `plt.figure`.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
pie = plt.pie(x, labels=labels, explode=explode, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=190,radius=2)
plt.legend(pie[0],labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5), loc="center right", fontsize=10, 
           bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
```

Try adding the `radius=2` (or something else in float too) to set the figure according to your needs.

`plt.legend` will give you what you are looking for but this will not make a line but the spacing will be taken care of. You can change the coordinates in the given legend and increase/decrease the size and place of legend too.